# Use LINQ to store in Hashtable

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to use LINQ to get data from DB and store it in Dictionary.
I can do LINQ and store it in a `List<Class_B>` and then iterate through the list and store it in `Dictonary<Class_A,List<Class_B>>`. But is it possible to directly store in the Dictionary?

Comment: Yes, use the `ToDictionary()` method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: have a look at `ToDictonary`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

System.Linq.Enumerable has a [ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method.

Here's an example from [dotnetperls.com](http://www.dotnetperls.com/todictionary):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Example integer array.
        int[] values = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7 };

        // First argument is the key, second the value.
        Dictionary<int, bool> dictionary = values.ToDictionary(v => v, v => true);

        // Display all keys and values.
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, bool> pair in dictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pair);
        }
    }
}
```